# Moved from pip to poetry and now pytest-cov won't collect coverage data

Tags: python, pytest, tox, coverage.py, python-poetry

I recently started using `poetry` to manage project dependencies,
rather than using `requirements.txt` and `test-requirements.txt` and
`pip`.

Since making the change, I'm not able to get coverage tests to work
correctly.  In both cases, I'm using `tox` to drive the testing (and I
have the `tox-poetry` extension installed).

My `tox.ini` currently looks like this:

```
[tox]
isolated_build = True
envlist = pep8,unit

[testenv]
whitelist_externals = poetry

[testenv:venv]
commands = {posargs}

[testenv:pep8]
commands =
    poetry run flake8 {posargs:symtool}

[testenv:unit]
commands =
    poetry run pytest --cov=symtool {posargs} tests/unit
```

Previously, it looked like this:

```
[tox]
envlist = pep8,unit

[testenv]
usedevelop = True
install_command = pip install -U {opts} {packages}
deps = -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt
    -r{toxinidir}/test-requirements.txt

[testenv:venv]
commands = {posargs}

[testenv:pep8]
commands =
    flake8 {posargs:symtool}

[testenv:unit]
commands =
    pytest --cov=symtool {posargs} tests/unit
```

Since making the change to `poetry`, when I run e.g. `tox -e unit`, I see:

```
unit run-test: commands[0] | poetry run pytest --cov=symtool tests/unit
===================================== test session starts =====================================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
cachedir: .tox/unit/.pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lars/projects/symtool, configfile: tox.ini
plugins: cov-2.11.1
collected 14 items

tests/unit/test_disasm.py .....                                                         [ 35%]
tests/unit/test_symtool.py .........                                                    [100%]r
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
```

I'm trying to figure out that `no-data-collected` issue. According to
`pytest --help`, the `--cov` arguments set the path **or** package
name:

```
 --cov=[SOURCE]        Path or package name to measure during execution
```

The root of the repository (which is `rootdir` in the above output
from `tox`) looks like this:

```
asm
pyproject.toml
README.md
reference
symtool
tests
tox.ini
```

There's definitely a `symtool` directory there containing the package.
And even if the tests were somehow not running in the project root
directory, the `symtool` package is installed in the test environment,
as evidenced by the fact that the unit tests are actually passing (all
of which include some variant of `import symtool`).

How do I get coverage to work again?

Comment: This is an old issue with `pytest-cov` and `tox`. `tox` installs your project and imports it from `.tox/unit/.../site-packages`, while `--cov=symtool` instructs `pytest-cov` to collect coverage over the `symtool` dir in project root. This is where an `src` layout really shines - you ignore the sources completely and run `tox` tasks over what's installed.

Comment: There are also workarounds possible, like prohibiting package installation in `tox` and invoking `poetry install` somewhere in `commands_pre` to ensure a development install. However, this is not the right way IMO.

Comment: You can also read through [issue #38](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-cov/issues/98), but mind that some advices may be outdated/not compatible with `poetry` (the issue _is_ old, after all) and some advices are just garbage.

Comment: @hoefling using a src layout seems to solve the problem. Are you interested in posting that as an answer along with some details? I'd be happy to write it up otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer:

This is an old issue with `pytest-cov` and `tox` (first reported in [issue #38](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-cov/issues/98)). `tox` installs your project as a third-party package and `pytest` will import it from the site (e.g. from `.tox/unit/lib/python3.X/site-packages` if the job is named `unit`), while `--cov=symtool` instructs `pytest-cov` to collect coverage over the `symtool` dir in project root.

One solution is to switch to the `src` layout:

```
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── reference
├── src
|   └── symtool
├── tests
└── tox.ini
```

In your `pyproject.toml`, you will need to point `poetry` to source dir:

```
[tool.poetry]
...
packages = [
    { include = "symtool", from = "src" },
]
```

Now `src` will prevent importing code from the source tree, so `--cov=symtool` will collect coverage over installed modules, this being the only option. For the rest of the dev process, you shouldn't get into trouble as `poetry install` installs the project in editable mode, so the rest should just work.

Another option is to skip package installation with `tox` and install in editable mode instead. Example snippet to place in `tox.ini`:

```
[testenv]
whitelist_externals =
    poetry
skip_install = true
commands_pre =
    poetry install
commands =
    poetry run pytest ...
```

This pretty much kills testing of the installed modules though (you stop testing explicitly whether your project can be installed in a blank venv, instead using what's in the source tree), so I'd go with the `src` layout option.

Comment: Thanks! That totally solved my problem, and I hadn't really though in detail about the implications of src vs non-src layout before.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using poetry, you probably like to use the locked dependencies for pytest, flake8, ... in tox as well. This can be achieved with [tox-poetry-installer](https://pypi.org/project/tox-poetry-installer/).

To make sure, your tests run against the build and installed package and not the local files, you must use the [--import-mode](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/pythonpath.html#import-modes) flag for pytest and set it to `importlib`.

To measure the coverage with pytest-cov, you have to point to the [{envsitepackagesdir}](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html).

To put it all together, your `tox.ini` can look like this:

```
[tox]
isolated_build = true
requires =
    tox-poetry-installer[poetry] == 0.6.0
envlist = py39

[testenv]
locked_deps =
    pytest
    pytest-cov
commands = pytest --cov {envsitepackagesdir}/mypackage --import-mode=importlib
```

**What is `--import-mode` doing?**

To run the tests, `pytest` needs to import the test modules. Traditionally this is done by prepending the path to the root folder where the discovered test folder is located to [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path). Usually the test folder and the package folder share the same root folder. So the side effect of prepending to sys.path is, that tests run against the package folder and not the installed package, because python find's this folder first.

Instead of prepending to `sys.path`, one can advice `pytest` to append the discovered root folder to it. Doing this python will first look at the site-packages folder when trying to import. So one can test against the installed package.

Manipulating `sys.path` is almost always a bad idea, as it can to lead unwanted side effects. The [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/pythonpath.html) of `pytest` describes one:

> Same as prepend, requires test module names to be unique when the test directory tree is not arranged in packages, because the modules will put in sys.modules after importing.

The third option for `importlib`, was introduced with pytest 6. This uses pythons build-in `importlib` to load a test module dynamically without manipulating `sys.path`. They plan do make this option the default one in a future release.

Comment: That's an interesting solution! Why is the `--import-mode=importlib ` necessary? I thought it only manages the tests discovery.

Comment: @hoefling: I've added some information about it to my answer.